# Returning values from an array

Tags: php

Is there any reason why this code would avoid the first value in an array?

```
$rappels = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach($row as $key=>$val) {
        $rappels[$i][$key] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
}
return $rappels;
```

When I return the rappels, it always seems to avoid returning the very first item, which should be [0] in the array.

Comment: The inner loop is unnecessary. You could replace the entire foreach with `$rappels[$i] = $row;`. You could even get rid of the `$i++` by moving it into the assignment. `$rappels[$i++] = $row;`. But this does make it a little less readable. And you could get rid of it all together by just assigning to `$rappels[]` (no key) which is just an array_push (append to array).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Well, that helps make it shorter, but it still works the same way, skipping the first item that would normally be returned when just running the SQL query.

Comment: There is nothing in that code that would skip a row.

Comment: The array pointer of `$row` is getting pushed ahead by calling 2 loops this way. `while` is setting the pointer to position `0`, then foreach is moving it to `1` where you first begin to do work.

Comment: Yep, as @JonathanKuhn says, the code seems to work correctly, probably the bug is somewhere else in the code

Comment: @phpisuber01 How exactly is the foreach incrementing the pointer?

Comment: @phpisuber01 nope. AFAIK, foreach will rewind the iterator and what he lacks isn't some column, but rows.

Comment: Could you show more code? Perhaps you are calling `fetch_assoc` before the while loop. Each call to `fetch_assoc` will increment an internal pointer in the result to the next row which is why the while loop works. Each iteration it returns the current row (or false if it doesn't exist) and moves the internal pointer to the next. If you were calling `fetch_assoc` before the loop, the loop would start on the second row. I would suggest including everything from creating the query to binding through this code.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://3v4l.org/NRE2o) the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of redundancies in your code.  You don't need `$i` nor do you need the foreach loop.

```
$rappels = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rappels[] = $row;
}
return $rappels;
```

Your code as you posted it shouldn't remove any rows.  You may need to look at the code you haven't posted to see if there's something there that's skipping the first row.